# How to interpret R's Unit Root Tests?

Tags: r, unit-testing

I want to apply an ARDL model to a data set of 5 yearly time series (one response and 4 explanatory), spanning from 1971 to 2014. After some research, I found that an ARDL model requires each series to be either I(0) or I(1), therefore a unit root test is necessary. However, when I run the Augmented Dickey-Fuller test in R, I obtain some conflicting results. For example, I have the following series (Energy Intensity):

[image: Energy Intensity]

When I run the following test, I obtain results suggesting the presence of a unit root both at the levels and at the differences:

```
> summary(ur.df(lnEI, type = "none", selectlags = "AIC"))

############################################### 
# Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test Unit Root Test # 
############################################### 

Test regression none 


Call:
lm(formula = z.diff ~ z.lag.1 - 1 + z.diff.lag)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.163622 -0.032769 -0.008332  0.038339  0.119160 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
z.lag.1     0.002252   0.005254   0.429    0.670
z.diff.lag -0.140916   0.177746  -0.793    0.433

Residual standard error: 0.0507 on 40 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.0201,    Adjusted R-squared:  -0.02889 
F-statistic: 0.4103 on 2 and 40 DF,  p-value: 0.6662


Value of test-statistic is: 0.4286 

Critical values for test statistics: 
      1pct  5pct 10pct
tau1 -2.62 -1.95 -1.61
```

But when I run the same test on the difference series, the results suggest the absence of a unit root.

```
> summary(ur.df(diff(lnEI), type = "none", selectlags = "AIC"))

############################################### 
# Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test Unit Root Test # 
############################################### 

Test regression none 


Call:
lm(formula = z.diff ~ z.lag.1 - 1 + z.diff.lag)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.16892 -0.03775 -0.01409  0.03200  0.11278 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
z.lag.1    -1.184667   0.285742  -4.146 0.000177 ***
z.diff.lag -0.003405   0.181897  -0.019 0.985160    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.05004 on 39 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.5329,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.509 
F-statistic: 22.25 on 2 and 39 DF,  p-value: 3.573e-07


Value of test-statistic is: -4.1459 

Critical values for test statistics: 
      1pct  5pct 10pct
tau1 -2.62 -1.95 -1.61
```

Again, when I put `type = "trend"`, the test shows there is no unit root.

```
> summary(ur.df(lnEI, type = "trend", selectlags = "AIC"))

############################################### 
# Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test Unit Root Test # 
############################################### 

Test regression trend 


Call:
lm(formula = z.diff ~ z.lag.1 + 1 + tt + z.diff.lag)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.156747 -0.028750  0.006856  0.029374  0.112337 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept) -0.5420587  0.2683397  -2.020   0.0505 .
z.lag.1     -0.3777513  0.1804803  -2.093   0.0431 *
tt          -0.0010684  0.0006158  -1.735   0.0909 .
z.diff.lag  -0.0106914  0.1875746  -0.057   0.9548  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.04778 on 38 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.1682,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1025 
F-statistic: 2.561 on 3 and 38 DF,  p-value: 0.06916


Value of test-statistic is: -2.093 2.4162 3.4944 

Critical values for test statistics: 
      1pct  5pct 10pct
tau3 -4.15 -3.50 -3.18
phi2  7.02  5.13  4.31
phi3  9.31  6.73  5.61
```

Can someone please help me understand which of these tests I should report when writing my paper? Can I report a series as stationary if it is trend-stationary? Thank you in advance.

PS: These are all the remaining four series:

[image]

Comment: This is not really a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you need help interpreting results from statistical models, you should ask for help at [stats.se] instead. You are likely to get better help there.